# Как это работает? R"=====( )====="

Tags: c++, строки, c++11, стандарт, строковый-литерал

во многих примерах сталкивался с подобной обёрткой HTML, но не где не могу найти как это работает ни слова.. Вот такие примеры часто попадаются:

```
const char MAIN_page[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
            <TITLE>My first web page</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
<BODY>
    <CENTER>
            <B>Hello World.... </B>
    </CENTER>    
</BODY>
</HTML>
)=====";
```

Как работает данный метод обёртки текста в C++?

Comment: Это `HEREDOC`..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из стандарта (раздел 5.13.5)...

> `необработанная-строка: " посл-d-символов_opt ( посл-r-символов_opt ) посл-d-символов_opt "`
>
> Строковый литерал с префиксом R называется необработанным строковым литералом (raw string literal). Конструкция посл-d-символов служит разделителем. Завершающая посл-d-символов из конструкции необработанная-строка является той же самой последовательностью символов, что и начальная посл-d-символов. Конструкция посл-d-символов должна состоять не более чем из 16 символов.

Словом, обыденными словами: Если встречается `R"`, после которого идут какие-то символы и `(`, а в конце - `)` и *те же символы* с `"`, то то, что между `()`, рассматривается как просто строковый литерал без всяких esc-символов или иной обработки - как есть, со всеми переводами кареток и новыми строками.

[Сравните](https://ideone.com/8DfvuD):

```
const char* a = "\\\\\"\"\\\\";
const char* b = R"raw(\\""\\)raw";
```

Так что в вашем примере в строку помещается просто кусок HTML-текста.

Все эти `=====` - скорее для красоты, чем для гарантии, что **в строке** не встретится конечный ограничитель `)====="`.

Comment: Ну и зачем вы закрыли мой вопрос?( Я все равно не понял из этого ответа как мне заэкранировать скобки. И самое главное - нафига вообще так сделали? Есть какая-то возможность просто написать строку в которой бы игнорировались обратные слэши, но не было такой херни со скобками?

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК Еще раз, медленно, как для милиционера: *минимальная* строка - `R"( ... )"`, так что если ваша строка `\(\)`, то она должна иметь вид хотя бы `R"(\(\))"`

Comment: Офигеть теперь. То есть чтобы использовать raw строки я должен их все обрамлять еще в скобки? А нафига вообще так сделали? Мне просто интересно где был здравый смысл разработчиков стандарта плюсов когда они такую дичь придумали... Ни в одном языке я такого не встречал, а я их повидал немало.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК Напишите в комитет по стандартизации, чтоб они в следующий раз сначала с вами согласовали... Я, конечно, мог бы пояснить некоторые резоны, но разве вам с вашим опытом и знаниями нужны какие-то пояснения?...

Comment: Вам ли судить о моем опыте? Я просто не плюсовик. Так - мелкую работенку на плюсах подкинули и теперь втыкаю. А опыта на нормальных языках у меня вагон.