# std::regex_match не находит вхождений

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, c++11, std-regex

Либо я чего-то не понимаю, либо библиотека работает не так как все.

В общем, хотел разбить одну строку на подстроки, где разделитель `\r\n`, но не тут то было...

Тесты регулярок:

[`(.+)\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/qVax6Y/1)
[`^(.+)$\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/qVax6Y/2)
[`(.+)$\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/qVax6Y/3)

Какое выражение нужно `std::regex` что бы ему стало понятно что нужно разделить строки через разделители строк?

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string match_string =
    {
        "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "Host: 127.0.0.1\r\n"
        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0\r\n"
        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\n"
        "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3\r\n"
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"
        "DNT: 1\r\n"
        "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n"
        "\r\n"
    };

    std::regex split_lines {"(.+)\\s+"};
    std::smatch results;

    if(std::regex_match(match_string, results, split_lines))
    {
        std::cout << "Found: " << results.size() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А там точно нужен `regex_match`, а не `regex_search`?...

Comment: Зачем использовать регулярки для поиска подстроки?

Comment: @user7860670 Ну может, человек просто тренируется, перед тем как палить из пушки по достойным целям? :)

Comment: Дубликат вопроса [Как получить доступ более чем к одной подстроке, найденной smatch()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736374/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-smatch)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Хм, вопрос ведь не о том как получить более одной подстроки... А о том что мне вот не было понятно как работает `regex` в плюсах. Еще и минус влепили. Вопросу и ответу, ну ладно вопросу, но ответу то за что?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте [так](https://ideone.com/OBhgCI):

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    string match_string =
    {
        "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "Host: 127.0.0.1\r\n"
        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0\r\n"
        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\n"
        "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3\r\n"
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"
        "DNT: 1\r\n"
        "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n"
        "\r\n"
    };

    std::regex split_lines{R"=((.+)\s+)="};
    std::smatch results;

    while(regex_search(match_string, results, split_lines))
    {
        std::cout << results.str() << '\n';
        match_string = results.suffix();
    }

}
```

Comment: О как, а что делают `=` в выражениях?

Comment: [Raw string](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1074481/195342)... само выражение - `.+\s` Можете написать `split_lines{".+\\s"};`